# Facebook Api Can't Read All Statuses

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How come I can only see like 26 of my status messages when I enable my application? I would like to be able to see all of them. I have the following privileges enabled:
user_status, friends_status, read_stream, publish_stream,
offline_access.
I also set the limit = 0 when extracting, but that didn't seem to make to much of a difference. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If you set limit to 0, Facebook will still page the data using the default page size.  You could set limit to a really high number, although I don't know the highest number you can set it to.  What you can do is look at the response you get back from Facebook, and at the very end there should be a paging json object that will have links to the next/previous list of status updates.

It will look something like:

```
"paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...&limit=25&since=1306385716",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...&limit=25&until=1301543613"
   }
```

Use those to get the next set of results.